# Embedding Data Studio reports in an AppEngine Application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, looker-studio

We have a web app developed using AngularJS as front-end and Cloud Endpoints/AppEngine as backend services (Python). We use Datastore for OLTP and push data on daily basis to BigQuery for analytics/reporting. It's straightforward to use big query data for creating dashboards/reports in Data Studio but it is not clear how we can embed these reports in the web application.

Is it something that is currently supported by Data Studio? We want to leverage DS to create parameterized reports/dashboards consuming data from BigQuery and display these reports from within our web application developed using AngularJS.

Comment: did you try iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google Data Studio does not currently have an API to hook into. So you cannot use it in the way you describe. See [here](https://support.google.com/360suite/datastudio/answer/7226791?hl=en).